# Passing traffic from a script through proxy / tor network

Tags: proxy, tor

I am applying for a job that involves creating unit tests and end to end tests for a website. Right now, i am assigned with a task, in order to test my skills.

However, my country has blocked access to that website (betting website).

Is there a way to create my scripts, but pass them through a proxy or the tor network?

Sorry if the question is vague, i am new to cybersecurity and mostly a programmer.

Comment: Tor can be used as a socks5 proxy. How to use such a proxy inside a script is a pure programming question and thus off-topic here. Also, I've removed the *anonymity* tag since the question does not seem to be about anonymity but about bypassing a block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment above by @SteffenUllrich - when you install Tor on your system, part of the setup includes a SOCKS5 proxy running locally that routes to the Tor network.  By default, the SOCKS5 proxy runs on local port 9050.

You can run a simple test using `curl` to send a request to a web server through Tor:

```
curl --socks5-hostname localhost:9050 https://www.whatismyip.com/
```

The response from whatismyip.com should show the IP address of the Tor exit node, instead of your own.

Hopefully this simple example points you in the right direction.  If you are using a higher level language (such as python) to write your scripts, then the library for making https requests may include a provision for routing the request through a proxy.  For example, in python, this can be done using the `requests` library (see https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#proxies for more info).